# Adding value range tags to values in data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to add certain tags to values in my data frame, similar to adding a grade column to marks. The only difference being that the grade scales for each subject is different.

Reprex:

```
# Specifying grade range for each subject
range <- data.frame(Subject <- rep(c('Math','Physics'),each = 3),
                    Start <- c(91,81,71,81,61,41),
                    End <- c(100,90,80,100,80,60),
                    Grade <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],2),stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(range) <- c('Subject','Start','End','Grade')

# Marks data of students
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(Subject <- rep(c('Math','Physics'),each = 4),
                 Student <- rep(c('Eeny','Meeny','Miny','Mo'),2),
                 Marks <- c(sample(40:100,7,T),NA))
colnames(df) <- c('Subject','Student','Marks')
```

You may have noticed that there are cases in `df` where the marks scored by student do not fall under any grade range or the marks are missing. In such cases I want `NA` under the grade column.

This is what I've tried to do

`res <- merge(df,range) %>% filter(between(Marks,Start,End))`

But it give the following error:
`Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=24]`

And the reason for this may be that the `left` and `right` arguments must be a single value and not a vector in the `between()` function.
I might want to avoid this approach because it creates all possible combinations of match and then later filters the data. In my case, I have a large data frame which takes a more than a couple of minutes to just create the merged data frame. Also, I would miss the rows where marks do not fall under any grade range using this approach.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be just as easy to write a little function to do this for you ahead of the dplyr pipe:

```
grade_it <- function(marks, subject)
{
  helper <- function(x, y) 
  {
    z <- range$Grade[range$Start <= x & range$End >= x & range$Subject == y];
    if(length(z) == 1) return(z) else return("FAIL")
  }
  mapply(helper, marks, subject)
}
```

So now you can just do:

```
df %>% mutate(Grade = grade_it(Marks, Subject))
#>   Subject Student Marks Grade
#> 1    Math    Eeny    87     B
#> 2    Math   Meeny    50  FAIL
#> 3    Math    Miny    91     A
#> 4    Math      Mo    70  FAIL
#> 5 Physics    Eeny    70     B
#> 6 Physics   Meeny    89     A
#> 7 Physics    Miny    85     A
#> 8 Physics      Mo    NA  FAIL
```

Comment: Neat! This is exactly what I wanted. I thought there would be an inbuilt functionality in R (maybe some kind of `data.table` or `dplyr` solution) so never though about writing a function. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df %>% mutate(Grade = case_when(Subject == "Math" & Marks %in% 91:100 ~ "A",
                                Subject == "Math" & Marks %in% 81:90 ~ "B",
                                Subject == "Math" & Marks %in% 71:80 ~ "C",
                                Subject == "Physics" & Marks %in% 81:100 ~ "A",
                                Subject == "Physics" & Marks %in% 61:80 ~ "B",
                                Subject == "Physics" & Marks %in% 41:60 ~ "C",
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_))


 Subject Student Marks Grade
1    Math    Eeny    94     A
2    Math   Meeny    42  <NA>
3    Math    Miny    47  <NA>
4    Math      Mo    99     A
5 Physics    Eeny    55     C
6 Physics   Meeny    57     C
7 Physics    Miny    66     B
8 Physics      Mo    NA  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But I believe in my case this approach isn't friendly because firstly, I already have the `range` data frame in a .csv and second, there are more than just two (around 35) subjects in my actual `range` data frame

Comment: Oh I see. This `merge(df,range) %>% 
  filter(Start <= Marks & Marks <= End)` would scale but the solution from @AllanCameron also solves the "fail" problem.